# the way to make sum function in python openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to use sum function in excel file. The excel file content is changed everyday, so I don't know which row is right position in excel file.

The image of the excel file is the output that I want to do. The image is as followed. enter image description here
[image]

In this excel file, I need to make sum function from p5 to p29 and from r5 to r28 , but the excel content is changed next time. This is the coding what I did. If you have any idea, please let me know that.

This is the coding that I did as followed.

```
def btncmd():

total_df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in file_content:
    df = pd.read_excel(i, index_col=0)  # index_col = 0으로 설정할 경우 '발송업체' 열 삭제가 가능 / 원치않으면 index_col=0 삭제
    df.dropna(inplace=True, thresh=3)   # 값이 채워져있는 부분이 3개면 삭제하지 않지만 2개까지는 삭제
    df.drop('발송업체', inplace=True, axis=0)  # 발송업체라는 문구가 있는 행 모두 삭제


    total_df = total_df.append(df, ignore_index=True)

total_df

merged_excel_file = "D:/사업/발주 및 정산/정산/정산서/"+ txt_file.get() + ".xlsx"

total_df.to_excel(merged_excel_file, sheet_name = "Sheet1", index=False)

wb = load_workbook(merged_excel_file)
ws = wb.active

ws.insert_cols(1)  # 세로 1열 삽입
ws.insert_rows(1, 3) # 가로 3행 삽입

ws.title = 'Sheet1'

# 기본 내역 삽입하기
a1 = ws['a1']
a4 = ws['a4']
ws['a1'] = '직배송+위탁발송 정산용으로 주시면 되세요~~'
ws['a4'] = '발송업체'
ws['b4'] = '성명'
ws['c4'] = '전화번호'
ws['d4'] = '핸드폰번호'
ws['e4'] = '주소'
ws['f4'] = '마켓'
ws['g4'] = '옵션'
ws['h4'] = '수량'
ws['i4'] = '착불유무'
ws['j4'] = ''
ws['k4'] = '배송메시지'
ws['l4'] = ''
ws['m4'] = '주문번호'
ws['n4'] = '우편번호'
ws['o4'] = '단가'
ws['p4'] = '공급가'
ws['q4'] = '배송비'
ws['r4'] = '합계'

# 행과 열의 너비 조정
ws.column_dimensions['a'].width = 14.75
ws.column_dimensions['b'].width = 14.38
ws.column_dimensions['c'].width = 20.51
ws.column_dimensions['d'].width = 15.75
ws.column_dimensions['e'].width = 21
ws.column_dimensions['f'].width = 13.63
ws.column_dimensions['g'].width = 38.13
ws.column_dimensions['h'].width = 5.13
ws.column_dimensions['i'].width = 9.25
ws.column_dimensions['j'].width = 5.13
ws.column_dimensions['k'].width = 21.13
ws.column_dimensions['l'].width = 5.13
ws.column_dimensions['m'].width = 14.50
ws.column_dimensions['n'].width = 15.75
ws.column_dimensions['o'].width = 13.88
ws.column_dimensions['p'].width = 10.75
ws.column_dimensions['q'].width = 8.63
ws.column_dimensions['r'].width = 14.88

ws.row_dimensions[1].height = 57

a1.font = Font(size = 14)

# 테두리 적용
thin_border = Border(left=Side(style='thin'), right=Side(style='thin'), top=Side(style='thin'), bottom=Side(style='thin'))
a4.border = thin_border

# 배경색 적용
green_fill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFFCC', end_color='FFFFCC', fill_type='solid')
ws['a4'].fill = green_fill
ws['b4'].fill = green_fill
ws['c4'].fill = green_fill
ws['d4'].fill = green_fill
ws['e4'].fill = green_fill
ws['f4'].fill = green_fill
ws['g4'].fill = green_fill
ws['h4'].fill = green_fill
ws['i4'].fill = green_fill
ws['j4'].fill = green_fill
ws['k4'].fill = green_fill
ws['l4'].fill = green_fill
ws['m4'].fill = green_fill
ws['n4'].fill = green_fill
ws['o4'].fill = green_fill
ws['p4'].fill = green_fill
ws['q4'].fill = green_fill
ws['r4'].fill = green_fill
ws['s4'].fill = green_fill
ws['t4'].fill = green_fill
ws['u4'].fill = green_fill
ws['v4'].fill = green_fill
ws['w4'].fill = green_fill

gray_fill = PatternFill(start_color='999999', end_color='999999', fill_type='solid')
ws['a1'].fill = gray_fill
ws['b1'].fill = gray_fill
ws['c1'].fill = gray_fill
ws['d1'].fill = gray_fill
ws['e1'].fill = gray_fill
ws['f1'].fill = gray_fill
ws['g1'].fill = gray_fill
ws['h1'].fill = gray_fill
ws['i1'].fill = gray_fill
ws['j1'].fill = gray_fill
ws['k1'].fill = gray_fill
ws['l1'].fill = gray_fill
ws['m1'].fill = gray_fill
ws['n1'].fill = gray_fill

# 가운데정렬
a1.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='left', vertical='center')

# 셀 하단부 정리
last_row = ws.max_row
ws.cell(row=last_row + 9, column=1).value = '합계'

ws.cell(row=last_row + 9, column=1).border = thin_border
ws.cell(row=last_row + 9, column=2).border = thin_border
ws.cell(row=last_row + 9, column=3).border = thin_border
ws.cell(row=last_row + 9, column=4).border = thin_border
ws.cell(row=last_row + 9, column=5).border = thin_border
ws.cell(row=last_row + 9, column=6).border = thin_border
ws.cell(row=last_row + 9, column=7).border = thin_border
ws.cell(row=last_row + 9, column=8).border = thin_border
ws.cell(row=last_row + 9, column=9).border = thin_border
ws.cell(row=last_row + 9, column=10).border = thin_border
ws.cell(row=last_row + 9, column=11).border = thin_border
ws.cell(row=last_row + 9, column=12).border = thin_border
ws.cell(row=last_row + 9, column=13).border = thin_border
ws.cell(row=last_row + 9, column=14).border = thin_border
ws.cell(row=last_row + 9, column=15).border = thin_border
ws.cell(row=last_row + 9, column=16).border = thin_border
ws.cell(row=last_row + 9, column=17).border = thin_border
ws.cell(row=last_row + 9, column=18).border = thin_border

for i in range(5, last_row):
    val1 = ws.cell(i, 8).value  # H = 8
    val2 = ws.cell(i, 15).value  # Q = 17

    if val1 != None and val2 != None:
        ws.cell(i, 16).value = val1 * val2  # P = 16

    else:
        break

ws.cell(row=i - 1 + 9, column=16).value = f"=SUM(P5:P{i - 1})"
```

Comment: Just an offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
last_row = sheet.max_row                         # last_row = 29

for i in range(5, last_row):
    val1 = sheet.cell(i, 8).value                # H = 8
    val2 = sheet.cell(i, 17).value               # Q = 17

    if val1 != None and val2 != None:
        sheet.cell(i, 16).value = val1 * val2    # P = 16

    else:
        break

sheet.cell(row=i-1+9, column=16).value = f"=SUM(P5:P{i-1})"
workbook.save(fileName)
```

Try saving it to a different excel file, saving to same file causes some data loss.

Comment: Why use a loop?

Comment: I didn't solve the problem. In excel file, P5 = sum(H5*O5). loop, doesn;t work. I don't know the exact number of last_row, so I though it can have some hint in for loop, but I don't know the reason exactly.

Comment: Did you get an error? I did it for P5 = H5*Q5. What it does is that the loop calculates the product for an individual row, if there exists a value in corresponding H and Q column. Then at the end the SUM function is used for adding the products from P5 to P(i-1) where the last value was found.

Comment: I changed 'sheet' to 'ws', because I found an error of NameError: name 'sheet' is not defined. Is that a reason that is not working?

Comment: workbook = xl.load_workbook(fileName),
sheet = workbook.active, sheet is just an object corresponding to an excel sheet. It is not the reason.

Comment: You got an error or didn't got the results looking for?

Comment: yes. now I am trying to looking for. The result is that P5 is emply and not function. P20 = =SUM(P4:P5)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235214/discussion-between-rishab-mamgai-and-).